# Spring Boot 2: Two @ExceptionHandler methods for same exception type in different and unrelated classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I have classes A and B. Both are annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`. Also both classes have a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)`(note, both exception handlers are for the same exception type). Classes A and B are not in the same hierarchy.

The reason I have done this is that I have not a controll on class A , as it is in an external lib and I needed to override the behavior of class A's ExceptionHandler.

During debugging I see that both exception handlers are being registered in Spring Exception Handler Cache, but the exception resolver always picks the class B's method , ignoring the Class A(which comes with an external dependency). This is what I needed, but:

1. I want to understand why my custom one is being selected, and want to be sure that one day spring will not suddenly choose the one that comes with library.
2. Is there a way to totally disable the library's Exception Handler so that it will not even be registered in Exception Handler Cache ?

Comment: I think spring overrides the either of the one

Comment: Yeah, but I need to understand what's going on under the hood, what is the logic behind determining which one overrides the other to be sure that one day the ordering is not changed

Comment: The exception handler should only be used in case of errors in that specific controller. It shouldn't be used as a generic exception handler (that is only the case if the `@ExceptionHandler` is in an `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class). 2. No it isn't possible as it is scoped to the controller.

Comment: Both, my class and the one that comes with library, have @RestControllerAdvice annotation. They are not tied to any specific controller